# android app recommends working where I already work

Tags: bug, status-deferred, android-app, android-app-feed

Title says it all.  Upon opening the mobile app on Android, the jobs feed recommends working where I already work

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/76972/software-engineer-full-stack-developer-thyssenkrupp-system?a=pOtvfqPG08O

Let me clarify my question.  We have an ad to hire a js ninja because we really need one, so if you know js and some web development please apply...

In any event we have an ad for the company I currently work in.  Careers company pages have a section that tells you "who you'd work with".  In that section I am clearly there...as an employee of that company.

Now when I am logged into the mobile application there are job feeds.  The first job feed recommends that I work for the company I already work for.  Clearly this is a bug since Careers already knows that I work for that company.  So why can this not be filtered out of my feeds since obviously I am not interested in working for the company I am already working for?

Comment: Could you clarify some info? I assume this is for Android app, but the title says "mobile site". Also, regarding job recommendation, did you mean "it's the job that you're currently working at", or "just a general job, but you are already working at other company and don't want to see them"?

Comment: And how exactly should the app know where you work? That's really not a bug, not even close.

Comment: @AndrewT. the official apps (both iOS and android) show feed of questions and job recommendations, that's what he's talking about.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I figured it out. I only wanted to make sure there is no ambiguity on the question (the job link pretty much gave a clue though), but now you have clarified it. Thanks.

Comment: Shadow why couldn't it...careers shows you who you'd work with...of course its a bug.

Comment: On the careers page for our company and any company there is a section that says people you'd work with.  It shows me...but the mobile app recommends I work there.  I already work there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We actually don't use any information about your company page, or your individual CV, when deciding which jobs to show you. This will change in the future, though I don't have any estimates for you as to when.

There are a couple of things which influence the likelihood of seeing an ad for the company you work for, including how good of a fit we think you are for it, and how many job listings we have in your area (geography being the bigger factor). We only have 12 job listings within 20 miles of Auburn Hills, MI, so the chances of seeing that ad in that area is pretty high.

People may have mixed opinions about whether or not they want to see their own listings. For some, seeing their own listing is positive reinforcement - it shows that their listing is actually running, lets them see what other users see, and I think there are many devs who don't even realize their company is running ads on SO Careers, so when they see the ad pop up, they may have feedback to give their HR department (which we think is a good thing that should happen more often). Other people may react like you, essentially asking wtf? I'm not sure deciding on the correct behavior is as clear as you make it sound.

For what its worth, showing you an ad from your own company doesn't take away any impressions from your listing. We don't allocate a fixed number of impressions to job ads, and they're selected from a weighted random distribution, so the chances of other users seeing your ad aren't diminished by the fact that you are also seeing it.

I'm marking this as by-design for now since it's not even going to be possible in the near future. However, once we do start incorporating more data from Careers, we'll revisit this internally and we'll make a decision about what we think correct behavior should be at that time. I'm not promising we'll come to the conclusion you want though.

Comment: But Im the one who put up the ad, and generally speaking HR departments get input from their IT staff to run ads.  I happen to be the one who placed it there.  I guess I don't see why you couldn't filter it given you know the people who work for the company.

Comment: "generally speaking HR departments get input from their IT staff to run ads" - you might be sadly disappointed to learn how often that's not true.

Comment: But still I think my point is I'm fine with you guys looking into it at a later date, to me it shouldnt feed me a job I currently work at - given you know who works for a company.

Comment: Like I said, I make no promises about what we'll decide, but your input is noted.

Comment: In this case do I just accept this as an answer?

Comment: That's entirely your call. My goal wasn't to get a checkmark, my goal was to give you insight about the current state of things, and address the fact that it's something we'll consider at a later date. Hopefully I did that. If it changes down the road, I'll try to remember to update this answer.

Comment: I re-marked it as [tag:status-deferred] since maybe that's more appropriate.